# Comparing the password strength of random characters to random words.

Tags: combinatorics

Passwords with any ASCII printable character and passwords containing only words in the English dictionary are attacked equally using a guessing program that cycles between random words and random characters with a set minimum and maximum for each case. For simplicity we'll say the same algorithms used to guess are also used to generate the passwords.

The pass-phrase will be some combination of three to five words chosen randomly from one-million (about the number of words in the English language). 
$10^{6\cdot3} + 10^{6\cdot4} + 10^{6\cdot5}$ Combinations

After a pass-phrase is guessed a string is generated using a minimum of four characters chosen randomly from ninety-five potential letters, digits, and symbols. $95^4 + 95^5 + 95^6 + ...$

What maximum is needed for your random character password to be more secure against the guessing program than three to five random words ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sixteen

$95^4 + 95^5 + 95^6 + ... + 95^{16}\approx4.45\cdot10^{31}$

$10^{6\cdot3} + 10^{6\cdot4} + 10^{6\cdot5}\approx10^{30}$